# Keep QtCreator on top when debugging

Tags: c++, macos, qt, debugging, qt-creator

When debugging a Qt application, QtCreator (3.3.2) is always below the application being debugged, when a breakpoint is hit.

It isn't too much of an issue to move the window of the application aside, but this is not always possible when, for example, a QFileDialog is opened. That window remains on top of Qt Creator, obscuring the debugging info.

There's an option in the Debug menu "Show Application On Top", but this isn't available:

[image]

I suspect this only works with QML.

Does anyone know how to ensure that QtCreator is the topmost window when a breakpoint is hit?